# Multiple inheritance: usage of skipping 'virtual' keyword and refusing the diamond hierarchy?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I understand how and why do we have to use the `virtual` keyword to solve the "diamond problem", and create a class hierarchy like this:

```
   A
  / \
 /   \
B     C
 \   /
  \ /
   D
```

Code example:

```
class A { int a; public: A(int a) : a(a) {} };
class B : public virtual A { int b; public: B(int a, int b) : A(a), b(b) {} };
class C : public virtual A { int c; public: C(int a, int c) : A(a), c(c) {} };
class D : public B, public C { public: D(int a, int b, int c) : A(a), B(0, b), C(0, c) {} };
```

I couldn't find an answer to my question: **Why do we have to tell the compiler (using the `virtual` keyword) that we want to create a "diamond" class hierarchy? Why does the compiler not generate it automatically?**
If we don't use `virtual`, the compiler generates the class hierarchy below:

```
A     A
|     |
|     |
B     C
 \   /
  \ /
   D
```

Is there any programming situation where the second hierarchy is useful and works?
**EDIT** (to make my question clear): Why did they want us to use `virtual`? I suppose, the reason is that they wanted to give an option to us. Any example where the second class hierarchy is the best choice to use?

Comment: "Is there any situation where __blank__ is useful and works?" Will default to yes for basically anything in C++ with enough effort.

Comment: @Frank Sorry, but you didn't answer my question. I am curious, is there any specific problem where the second (U-shape) hierarchy is a great idea and also a good practice to use (with a given example).

Comment: The C++ philosophy is that you don't pay for what you don't use. If you don't *need* virtual inheritance, then according to the principles on which C++ was built, you shouldn't have to pay the performance costs associated with building that hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any programming situation where the second hierarchy is useful and works?

Although there might be, that becomes a less interesting question (in my opinion) after I've answered the other one.

> Why do we have to tell the compiler (using the virtual keyword) that we want to create a "diamond" class hierarchy? Why does the compiler not generate it automatically?

No, the compiler cannot generate it automatically.  That is why you have to tell the compiler explicitly when you want inheritance to be virtual.

Assuming such automation existed, in order for the compiler to guess that the base `A` of `B` should be virtual, it would have to know that `A` is also the base of `C`, and that `B` and `C` are both bases of `D`. So, the meaning of the definition of `B` would depend on the definition of `D` (which also depends on `C`. Essentially, all classes that are part of same hierarchy will depend in all other classes in that hierarchy, except the very top base). But some classes of the hierarchy may be defined in completely different translation units that may be compiled at a completely different time than the others. The C++ compiler simply cannot assume that it has knowledge of all classes.

There is one approach that would make this possible: Make all inheritance virtual. However, virtual inheritance has some (small, but non-zero) overhead, so this is not an ideal solution. Also, virtual inheritance makes static_cast to derived type impossible, so such cast would require dynamic_cast which requires Run Time Type Information and there is interest in allowing limited C++ implementations that lack RTTI support.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks! This proves why _virtual inheritance_ makes sense. I need to get good at thinking as a compiler.

Comment: But the definition of a class *does* depend on the definition of its superclass(es)! You can't inherit from an incomplete type, for example. The definitions of `B` and `C` necessarily need to be known for `D` to inherit them.

Comment: @cdhowie Correct. I changed my wording in case it was unclear that I wasn't implying otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where `A` is a [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) interface, while `B` and `C` implement this interface independently of each other, and need differing visitation behavior.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void visit(int) = 0;
};

class B : virtual private A
{
public:
    virtual void visit(int) { }
};

class C : virtual private A
{
public:
    virtual void visit(int) { }
};

class D : public B, public C { };
// error: virtual function 'A::visit' has more than one final overrider in 'D'
```

This [does not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/101c087efc642b41).  It is *desirable and necessary* in this case for `B` and `C` to retain separate `A` subobjects.  Removing the virtual inheritance in this example allows it to compile.